# How to add a custom GraphQL parameter in a GatsbyJS node?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I created the following gatsby node to query 1 record

```js
const axios = require("axios");

exports.sourceNodes = async (
  { actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest },
  configOptions
) => {
  const { createNode } = actions;

  // Gatsby adds a configOption that's not needed for this plugin, delete it
  delete configOptions.plugins;
  // Helper function that processes a post to match Gatsby's node structure
  const processPost = post => {
    const nodeId = createNodeId(`gutenberg-post-${post.id}`);
    const nodeContent = JSON.stringify(post);
    const nodeData = Object.assign({}, post, {
      id: nodeId,
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: `GutenbergPost`,
        content: nodeContent,
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(post)
      }
    });
    return nodeData;
  };

  const apiUrl = `http://wp.dev/wp-json/gutes-db/v1/${
    configOptions.id || 1
  }`;

  // Gatsby expects sourceNodes to return a promise
  return (
    // Fetch a response from the apiUrl
    axios
      .get(apiUrl)
      // Process the response data into a node
      .then(res => {
        // Process the post data to match the structure of a Gatsby node
        const nodeData = processPost(res.data);
        // Use Gatsby's createNode helper to create a node from the node data
        createNode(nodeData);
      })
  );
};
```

My source is a rest API that has the following format:

```
http://wp.dev/wp-json/gutes-db/v1/{ID}
```

Currently the gatsby node default ID set is 1

I can query it in graphql by doing this:

```
{
  allGutenbergPost {
    edges {
      node{
        data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will always return record 1

I wanted to add a custom parameter for ID so that I could do this

```
{
  allGutenbergPost(id: 2) {
    edges {
      node{
        data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What adjustments should I do with my existing code?

Comment: Using the new schema customization APIs you could use the `createResolvers` hook, then you wouldn't even need to source upfront, but let the query decide what to return https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-03-18-releasing-new-schema-customization/#createresolvers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are [creating page programmatically](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-pages-in-gatsby-nodejs)? If so, in the `onCreatePage` hook, when you do `createPage`, you can pass in a `context` object. Anything in there will be available as a query variable.

For example, if you have

```
createPage({
  path,
  component: blogPostTemplate,
  context: {
    foo: "bar",
  },
})
```

Then you can do a page query like

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  ExampleQuery($foo: String) {
    post(name: { eq: $foo }) {
      id
      content
    }
  }
`
```

---

If you just want to filter by id, you can check out the docs on [filter & comparison operators](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#filter).

```
{
  allGutenbergPost(filter: { id: { eq: 2 }}) {
    edges {
      node{
        data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  gutenbergPost(id: { eq: 2 }) {
    data
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!